# Info about to create a kanban winapp oriented

Tags: mysql, winforms, kanban

I would like to create a kanban WinApp. I would like to know which control I  would best off using. The main goal is to display kanban elements that are arranged by colored box, day by day.

I had thought about using a scheduler control. Is this the right choice?

Comment: This question will get closed because it's not appropiate for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Anyways, I strongly suggest WPF instead of winforms for this. winforms is a really old technology no one cares about anumore, and which does not support anything. You can achieve something like [this](http://www.javiergarzas.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/EJEMPLOKANBAN2.jpg) (if that's really what you're looking for) in WPF really easily by using some nested `ItemsControls`. Whereas it would take tons of horrible hacks in winforms (or spending lots of $$$ in buying third party components). Also, winforms is not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications.

Comment: Just in case you're interested, based in the above linked screenshot, I created [this sample](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WChgg.png) of such a thing using current, relevant .Net Windows UI technologies, in 50 lines of XAML and 10 lines of C# code. It took me less than 30 minutes. Full Source code [here](http://pastebin.com/q0NQUtg4)

Comment: your answer to me was very helpful. Thanks for the code example. Then I'll develop on WPF technology ...

Comment: please mark my answer as accepted if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting my comment into an  answer:

Based in the above linked screenshot, I created this sample of such a thing using current, relevant .Net Windows UI technologies:

[image]

In only 50 lines of XAML and 10 lines of C# code. 
It took me less than 30 minutes. Full Source code [here](http://pastebin.com/q0NQUtg4)

Comment: 30 Minutes from one with expertise like you is about a year from me :) - Nice work

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but since I've actually implemented a Windows Kanban app in WPF (https://www.xplan-taskmanager.com/), it might be of use to others.

The board itself is a hierarchy of DockPanel-ScrollViewer-DockPanel:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollPanel" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <DockPanel x:Name="panel" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Columns are StackPanels:

```
<StackPanel AllowDrop="True">
    <TextBlock Name="nameLabel"></TextBlock>
    <StackPanel Name="cardsPanel">
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Cards are also implemented as StackPanel.

Board, Columns, and Cards have all been created as UserControl.

[image: XPlan]

I'm pretty happy with the result but I see from profiling tests that performance could use some optimization. I still have to analyze alternatives but, for the moment, this works fine. Anyway, for large numbers, I've placed a "more" at the end of each column (just a button).